# Installing Linux on Windows XP

Tags: linux, installation, windows-xp, vmware

I have Linux in office and Windows XP at home. I sometimes want to have the home desktop env same as that of my office. I have RAM = 1 GB only.

Could anybody please tell me what steps I need to take to create that env? 
Is my RAM small for running two OS together?

Also since my siblings don't like to work on Linux, I want to set basic or main OS as Windows and Linux only for myself (as guest).
How can I do this? Do I need to install VMware etc.? What software is needed for that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you consider installing Linux on your home machine (instead, or aside of, Windows)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch aside of windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possible ways:

- Install a VM (eg. VirtualBox or VMware) and a lightweight Linux
- Install both systems on your system
- Use a life disc / life medium (eg. usb stick); there you can run linux without changing your computer
- Linux Mint supports an installation of Linux Mint on your windows (*mint4win*¹)

¹ This seems to have some issues on win xp.

---

**Documentation:**

- [Install Linux Mint on Your Windows Computer or Netbook](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20079/install-linux-mint-on-your-windows-computer-or-netbook/)
- [Guide To Install Linux Mint 16 In Dual Boot With Windows](http://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/)
- [For Newcomers - How to Install and Dual Boot Linux Mint 16 Onto a Windows 8 System (With UEFI)](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1556)
- [How to install Ubuntu/Linux Mint upon Windows using Wubi/Mint4Win?](http://www.thegeeksclub.com/26417-install-ubuntulinux-mint-windows-wubimint4win/)

---

- [Universal USB Installer, Install, Run Linux From USB](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/05/09/universal-usb-installer-install-run-linux-from-usb/)
- [Run Linux Mint 9 from a USB Flash Drive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/run-linux-mint-9-from-a-usb-flash-drive/)
- [Install Linux on USB drive](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/723)
- [Install Linux Mint On USB Drive And Walk With It: Portable Linux Mint](http://www.muktware.com/2011/05/install-linux-mint-on-usb-drive-and-walk-with-it-portable-linux-mint/1198)

Btw. you can *always* run LM in Live-mode (without changing something on your system): Just install the ISO onto your USB drive and boot in live mode. But in this case, your settings are lost if you shut down the system (however you can write files etc. to your harddrive).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. But could you please tell me how using the third method(using a USB stick)?

Comment: I haven't done this myself yet, so you have to search a bit. I put some links into may answer, but please read before trying and better look for some additional documentation if you are not sure.

Comment: If your question is solved, please *accept* the answer (click on the green tick), so the question is marked as *solved*.